# Unable to receive response after sending request with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have a simple POST request using Guzzle from Laravel to send. I tested the request with Postman but it keeps sending request until timeout without returning any response data. I set up some URLs to return sample data and they work fine when testing separately. But when bring the URLs to the request to call from Guzzle, then this sending-request-till-forever happened. Hope you guys can help me shed some light on this problem.

Here is my request code:

```
$client = new Client();
$req = new Request('POST', 'http://13.114.233.87/api/ocr');
$reqData = $client->send($req, ['timeout' => 5]);
return $reqData;
```

Here are the handlers for each sample URL:

```
(1) http://13.114.233.87/api/ocr

Route::post('ocr', 'OcrController@postOcrData'); // routing

public function postOcrData()
{
    return response()->json(collect([
        'request_id' => rand(0, 9),
        'result' => 0,
        'error_code' => '',
        'error_message' => ''
    ]));
}


(2) http://13.114.233.87/api/ocr/getResult/{id}

Route::get('ocr/getResult/{id}', 'OcrController@getOcrData'); // routing

public function getOcrData($id)
{
    return response()->json(collect([
        'request_id' => $id,
        'result' => 0,
        'error_code' => '',
        'error_message' => '',
        'fields' => []
    ]));
}
```

Comment: what's content-type of the post request?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I don't know. I don't explicitly set it. I don't think setting the content-type to something would make the request work, but as you asked I'll give it a try